# ROR import csv file no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ibm-midrange

the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `read' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/imports_controller.rb:5:in `upload'
```

I reworked my csv upload routine from my earlier question [Adding CSV Import to a ROR application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105381/adding-csv-import-to-a-ror-application)

I had found a question that was asked several years ago that seemed similar to what I wanted but some of the code was in Spanish [Ruby on Rails - Import CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442450/ruby-on-rails-import-csv-file)

imports_controller:

```
class ImportsController < ApplicationController    

def upload
logger.info "File loaded"
infile = params[:dump][:infile].read
n, errors = 0, []
@archive = []
CSV.parse(infile) do |row|
  n += 1
  # SKIP: header i.e. first row OR blank row
  next if n == 1 or row.join.blank?
  imports = Imports.build_from_csv(row)
  if imports.valid?
    imports.save
    @archive << row
  else
    errors << row
  end
  end
logger.info errors
flash[:success] = "The CSV imported successfully" 

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @archive }
    end
 end 
end
```

*note that there seems to be extra end but until I added them I was getting an application error

models/imports.rb:

```
class Imports < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.build_from_csv(row)
 #last_level = (row[5].downcase == "yes"
     imports = Imports.new(:imports => "#{row[0]}}",
                            :cart_items => "#{row[1].titlesize}",
                            :cart_items_quantity => "#{row[2].titlesize}",
                            :cart_items_price => "#{row[3].titlesize}",
                            :cart_items_description => "#{row[4].titlesize}",
                            :cart_items_upc => "#{row[5].titlesize}",
                            :cart_items_sku => "#{row[6].titlesize}")
                           # :last_level=> last_level)
return imports
end
end
```

and here is the form call that I use to upload the csv:

```
<h3>Import CSV Order</h3>                                
                 <% form_for :dump, :url=>{:controller=>"imports", :action=>"upload"}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
                     <table">
                       <tr>
                         <td>
                          <label for="dump_file">
                            Select a CSV File :
                          </label>
                         </td>
                         <td >
                           <%= f.file_field :infile -%>
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                         <td colspan='2'>
                           <%= submit_tag 'Submit' -%>
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
```

So any thoughts on the no method error would be much appreciated. As you can tell I am new to Ruby and this was an inherited app so any help is most welcome!
thanks

Comment: like the error says `params[:file]` is nil, in your form you used `infile`, so maybe try `params[:infile]` ?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion...still same error

Comment: then you need to inspect the params and see what's being sent. try a debugger, or if u don't have one try `puts params.inspect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's `nil`. It's not where you are expecting it to be. Your `form_for :dump` semantically constructs a form for object "dump". It is represented by a hash in `params` by the corresponding key. So, actually, that parameter is over there:

```
params[:dump][:infile]
```

Comment: so should '<% form_for :dump, :url=>{:controller=>"imports", :action=>"upload"}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>' read differently?

Comment: @bobkendall it's more like the controller code should be fixed to reference the correct thing.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! that did help now issue is SV.parse(infile) do |row| i tried CSV.parse(infile) do |row| which in inintialized constant so I thought infile.parse(infile) do |row| made more sense but it is  throwing undefined method for parse do I need an object for parse in the form?

Comment: I added require 'csv' which corrected the CSV.parse(infile

Comment: could really use help with related issue involving same code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374796/ror-import-csv-file-undefined-method  my aplogies if you've already seen- thanks in advance